# Is it possible to cache an HTML page in a way that it can be requested from multiple URIs?

Tags: javascript, html, http, caching, single-page-application

I'm in the process of building a single-page web application with friendly URLs. As an example, for a chat you could request `/chat/roomname` or `/chat/roomname2` to connect to a different chatroom. Since this is an SPA however, both of those would lead to the same HTML contents.

Is it possible to tell the browser to cache both pages as a single page (as in, going to /chat/roomname would also cache /chat/roomname2 in the browser), or something that would give a similar effect? This way the HTML contents could be large and only have to be loaded once.

Alternatively I could do /#/chat/roomname or similar, though I'd prefer not to if the above is possible.

Comment: This is typically handled by server side code, it's not caching that you're after, it's simply url redirection.

Comment: How about changing your URL structure to `/chat?roomname=1`. This will cache `/chat` and then you have your flexibility of changing room names

Comment: @zzzzBov, that's not what I'm looking for though. It would look mighty weird if /chat/roomname2 redirected to /chat/roomname even though they're not the same thing.

Comment: @jibsales, I'm actually pretty sure that won't be cached as the same page. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @KMorrow, I shouldn't have said redirect, I should have said url rewriting. For something like a LAMP stack, you'd use an `.htaccess` file to change the request to point to something like `index.php` for every request and let php handle the page.

Comment: @zzzzBov, fair enough. That being said, I'm looking specifically at client-side caching rather than server-side. Sorry if my original post/comments weren't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate paths are separate things for the browser. Even the same pages with different query parameters are treated different (hence, the "cache busting" technique). However...

You can:

- Off-load all scripts to external scripts so the browser caches them separate from the page.
- Do the same with CSS as well.
- Keep the page to a bare minimum.
- If the resources (scripts, styles, images) won't be modified for a long period of time, you can set a longer expiry for them.
- Instead of loading the entire layout using HTML, you can use AJAX to fly in templates. That way, those layout requests get cached as well. Have JS assemble them when they're needed.

In the end, your pages will be devoid of all JS, CSS and markup that can be flown in and assembled using JS. This will make the page lighter than usual. You can take it a step further by minifying the scripts and styles, compressing images, compress the HTML and stuff.

Comment: I should have clarified a bit. The HTML itself is completely static - everything that's to be loaded is done via XHR, WebSocket, localStorage, etc.